# Why is my Connected App status 'Pending'/'Unpublished changes'

Tags: rest-api

I am trying to enable the REST API. I created a new 'Connected App' on the Apps page. It seemed to work initially (?) but now that I changed the Callback URL it seems to be stuck in the 'Unpublished changes' state.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to give your dev org a namespace by creating a managed package first, then you can publish your connected app.

It's not terribly well documented.

Answer (score 0):

https://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_connected_apps.pdf

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Connected_Apps

The connected app feature is a pilot feature .Problem is sometimes we update the connected app and forget to make it published .I would suggest to use publish button and make the app publish.The REST API then become available .Only thing is you may have to append connected app name in the REST service URL to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

With Summer '13 comes the ability to package Connected Apps.  Because of this, you no longer need to Publish the app as you did prior to Summer '13 and Hence the publish button is gone forever.

Instead, simply create a package and add the Canvas App to the package (Canvas Apps are listed under Connected Apps in the component selector).  Once you have added it to the package, simply upload your package.

Note, Canvas Apps (and Connected Apps) can only be added to a Managed Package.